# The Problem with Installing XAMPP on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, php, xampp

I just installed XAMPP 1.7.3 on Windows 7 64 bit, every things was going well but Apache ! 
Apache didn't start at all ! 
I already installed the Apache's service but it doesn't work yet.

Would you please guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. 
We have to install XAMPP on the default path (C:\xampp) on Windows 7
I've done it and it works well :)

Comment: Use XAMPP Lite next time and save yourself some headaches. =)

Comment: What's the difference between XAMPP Lite & XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP Lite is a portable version. It is configured with relative paths so that it can be run from usb. No need for configuration. It includes PHP, MySQL, Apache, PhpMyAdmin and XAMPP Control Panel.

It is not necessary to install XAMPP only to c:\xampp. If you install it to a different location, you have to configure the paths. You can do that easily from XAMPP control panel config.